# Android add Button inside TextView programmatically

Tags: android

i want add `Button` in middle of text in `TextView`, like when i see a phone number in text, replace it with a `Button` in `TextView`, and set background of `Button` to a contact picture, but how can i add `Button` to `TextView` ? is it possible ?

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: A textview is for text, not buttons

Comment: Better to hide or show the view.Suppose, if any case you don't want button then progromatically setVisibility(View.gone) and add the textview already and hide the visibility to gone and whenever needed visible the needed view

Comment: thanks @HarshParikh, see my comment in vishal answer

Comment: better to play with visibility, take imageview or imagebutton for contact picture in a relative layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about placing a widget(or view) inside a widget. This is not possible. You can only add widgets inside layouts. However, you can position a widget on top of another widget if you will use a relative layout.

Refer : developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Comment: thanks @vishal but i don't know where it might be place, is it possible to catch the position of phone number in a text and set it as margin to another layout ?

Comment: May be place button to the right of the TextView (or somewhere else) and use an ImageButton. Whenever the TextView finds a phone number, the image of the ImageButton is replaced. Simple If-then-else would do this, i hope.

Comment: I didn't get this part "is it possible to catch the position of phone number in a text and set it as margin to another layout ?"

Comment: ok i accept your answer for possibility of placing a widget inside a TextView

Answer (score 1):

I think you dont need button in textview.Its a combination of views means viewgroup is sufficient 
relativelayout will do the job

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="normaltext" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/contactpicture"
    android:text="phonenumber"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

depending on the text change the visiblity of TextView and button.
Hope it helps you.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Basically you cant place any `Button` inside a `TextView`. One approach to this sort of problems is to programmatically partition the text into different parts and i.e add a `Button` between `TextViews` whenever you meet a number. So lets say you have a text: "*The number 123456 is my phone number*", you would need to split into three parts: "*The number*", "*123456*", " *is my phone number*" and create the widgets accordingly i.e `<TextView/> <Button/> <TextView/>`